# Adding facebook login to an app in localhost

Tags: javascript, facebook

I know this question have been asked and asked, but I still cannot manage to make it work.

To put it simply: I want to integrate Facebook login into a web app that I'm building. I used the FB JS SDK and it loads successfully, when I click to the "Login button" it opens me a popup asking for basic permissions, and then... error.

I went into the Facebook dashboard, set the Site redirect URL to:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp.
```

The console gives me this after Allowing:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080"
```

And when I try to access from https, I get:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://localhost:8080". The frame requesting access set "document.domain" to "facebook.com", but the frame being accessed did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.
```

I've looked and looked, but nothing could help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I had an issue using localhost with Facebook applications. What I ended up doing was to create an entry in my host file on my computer to point fbdev.com to localhost and just used "fbdev.com" in place of localhost in the app settings on facebook

Comment: I tried to do that too, but nothing can do... I'm losing my mind here.